# Spaces in file path break shell script even with quotes

Tags: bash, macos, shell, path

I'm trying to write a script to run my .jar file with a specified JRE. It seemed that relative paths weren't working, so I figured that "relative" meant relative to somewhere other than the script itself, and I needed to use $BASH_SOURCE. Anyway, it echoes just fine, but when it comes time to run the command to launch the .jar, I get a "No such file or directory" error, and it shows a directory truncated at the first space.

I understand this question has been asked a million times, but every one that I've looked at the answer is so simple as just adding some double quotes. I've done that. I've spent the last hour adding every possible ridiculous combination of double quotes I could think of and it's done nothing. At best I get the same issue, and at worst it replaces the whole string with "??". In the sample below, I used quotes when defining the variables, but I have also tried putting the quotes in the last line instead. It still doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=${BASH_SOURCE%/*}
pathjar=“${dir}/thebox.jar”
echo $pathjar
pathjre=“${dir}/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java”
Echo $pathjre
$pathjre -jar $pathjar
```

I've also tried replacing the $pathjar with a random string of characters just to troubleshoot where the error is. Since the error is unchanged, I figure it must be with the $pathjre variable or maybe both.

Comment: `bash` doesn't have any `Echo`. Hope it is just a typo..

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash -x` to debug the script.

Comment: Yeah, that is a typo. I'm running it in a Mac virtual machine and writing it in some stupid notepad thing that autocorrects and capitalizes words.

Answer (score 0):

The editor I was using was changing my double quotes to the fancy double quotes. It works fine with normal double quotes. Well, I guess this is useful in case someone happens to stumble upon this question and made the same mistake...